# Recommended IDE to develop for Websphere App Server other than RAD

Tags: ide, websphere

WAS is not famous for being an easy platform to develop for if you're not using RAD. Any hints or tricks to do so with netbeans, eclipse, idea, emacs/vi/ant ? Is it even possible to develop the application on top of - for instance - tomcat and then deploy it with confidence to a WAS - 6.1 - server ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MyEclipse Blue 8.5 onwards is good option as RAD replacement. WAS 7 DE is free from IBM, so MyEclipse Blue+WAS7 DE is a killer combo. You will save 90% of IDE cost.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you build your web app using the same versions of your WAS environment (jre/Java EE/etc) it should work.

MyEclipse has a version (Blue) that has full websphere support.  It isn't free but it looks pretty good...

http://www.myeclipseide.com/

Comment: Does it set IBM's JDK as runtime ?

Comment: I think you would have to specify it manually by telling it to use the JVM of your websphere install.  I confess I have not tried this at all but it should work, possibly with additional environment set up.  You might want to post a question on the myeclipse support forums...
http://www.myeclipseide.com/PNphpBB2-viewforum-f-1.html